# How to update table row and add + 1 in row field?

Tags: php, mysql, count, row

I have troubles with this few days. Still learning.. Anyway - through this input

```
form action='votes.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='WHATNAME' value='WHAT?'/>
<input class='voteUp' type='submit' name='submitUp' value='+'/>
</form>
```

I want to update table! And i would like to update 'voteup' filed with + 1, and only that. HEre is table Answers

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `answer` text,
  `questionId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255),
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ip` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `voteup` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );
```

Here is second table Questions

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question` text NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `datum` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

So, with this, I have a table questions and every question could have a lot of answers. So i would like and i need to make that somebody can vote (voteup) for every answer that he think it is correct. So far i make success with vote up for only one answer, and if I put second answer, it gives me some weird multiple and double count numbers. Here is mysql query from file Votes.php that update me voteup, but Only when i have one question!

```
if (isset($_POST['submitUp'])) {  

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql="INSERT INTO answers
SET voteup = voteup + 1,
ip = '$ip'  
";
```

And here is select count script that shows me how many votes is there

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(voteup) as voteup FROM answers ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
  {

  echo $row['voteup'];

  }
```

How to update voteup field for every answers with different questions Id. I try few combinations but Nothing! I hope i was clear. And thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the question ID to the script as well:

```
<form action='votes.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='<?php echo $question_id; ?>'/>
<input type='hidden' name='answer_id' value='<?php echo $answer_id; ?>'/>
<input class='voteUp' type='submit' name='submitUp' value='+'/>
</form>
```

And the Votes.php should do an update based on those values (also look up securing your queries: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) :

```
if (isset($_POST['submitUp'])) {  
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $question_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['question_id']);
  $anwer_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['answer_id']);
  $sql="UPDATE answers
        SET voteup = voteup + 1,
        ip = '$ip'
        WHERE id = $answer_id
        AND questionId = $question_id
        ";
}
```

Note that IP in this case only reflects the IP of the last upvote. To record the IPs of every upvote you'll need a separate table for storing upvote IPs.